# What would be the best way to compare CSV data in Java?

Tags: java, csv, collections, hashmap, compare

What I am trying to do is:

- Read two separate CSV files into some sort of Java objects
- Based on input data to a program, compare against this csv data for the purpose of validation and returning a JSON response

The first CSV file looks something like this:

```
Car, Model
Toyota, Corolla
Toyota, Avensis
Subaru, Impreza
Ford, Kuga
```

The second breaks down some detail on the Models:

```
Model, BHP, Fuel Type
Corolla, 150, Diesel
Avensis, 180, Petrol
Impreza, 220, Petrol
Kuga, 110, Diesel
```

Basically, I want to interrogate this data after inputting something like:

Car: "Toyota"
BHP: 300

The above would return a message saying that there are no Toyota cars with a BHP of 300.

I was thinking that the way to go about this is to read the CSV data into Java Maps or standard POJOs and perform the comparisons from there.

Maps can get overly complex fairly quickly when dealing with a lot of data. Is there a better, more obvious way that I am not thinking of?

NOTE: I cannot use a database for this. This must all be driven from CSV with no persistent storage.

Comment: *"Is there a better, more obvious way that I am not thinking of?"* - A database?

Comment: Whoops, I should have mentioned that I cannot use a database for this. But fair point! I'll update the question.

Comment: In that case, probably there isn't.

Comment: Fair enough, I was struggling to think up of alternatives. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I couldn't tell you the "best" solution, but you can join the two tables and load it into a Collection of Car objects with fields "Manufacturer,Model,BHP,Fuel type", and the streams API is a nice way to filter the list down to the elements that satisfy some criteria.

Comment: I think you can use Arrays to do this. first load the 2 csv files to two arrays. Then you can compare the array. is it okay for you ?

Comment: Two good suggestions, thank you both. I will give them a go.